# Matrix-valued differential equation involving inverse

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $X(t)$ be a matrix-valued function which outputs symmetric and positive definite matrices for all $t$.

How can i solve

$$ 
\ddot{X}(t)= \alpha(t) X^{-1}(t).
$$
where $\alpha(t)$ is some scalar. Additionally, i want to apply some initial conditions as $\dot{X}(0) =Y$ and $X(0)=X_0$.

I searched through literature and i tried a few things on my own, but i wasn't able to get something useful here. I also tried some ansatzes and solving for coefficients e.g.

$$
X(t) = X_0 \exp(t X_0^{-1} Y)
$$
but i always arrived at dead ends.

Can someone give me a hint or point me to some literature? Is the first order equation easier: $\dot{X}(t)= \alpha(t) X^{-1}$?

**Edit:** Add time dependence of $\alpha$.

Comment: Have you tried the $1 \times 1$ case?

Comment: In the 1d case, there is some solution to the second order equation, involving the inverse error function. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%27%27%28x%29%3Da%2Ff%28x%29. But i thought there is a better way? Or is the only way diagonalizing and apply this?

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: I want to derive the Riemannian exponential map on the manifold of symmetric positive definite matrices with constant determinant. The above mentoined differential equation arises in my derivation